# Table doesn't expand when adding new data (from .csv files in my case)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Lets say I got some external .csv files which I got updated and I just need to hit the refresh button in Power Query to make some magic - that works fine, BUT, there some columns which are information about some parts, and I need to lookup values for them in another .csv file. What I did here is, I didnt convert all 4 Columns in a Table, but I separated them, each column has another name (table name) because I had some issues with refreshing from Power Query, and seemed easier to do calculation first and then convert to table.. maybe that was not smart tough??

My question is and issue actually, I am not getting new rows with new data beneath my "tables" I must drag it down to populate. Why that occurred?

These are functions I used from starting Column:

```
=INDEX(Matrix[[#All];[_]];ROW())
```

Then others are just lookup ones depending which info I am looking for:

```
=INDEX(variantendb[Vartext];MATCH(C2;variantendb[Variante];0))
```

And last column and calculation is **concatinating** to have Info name and Code together:

```
='0528 - info'!$D2 & " "& "("&'0528 - info'!$C2&")"
```

And of all of them I made in 5x Tables SEPARATELY, not as one table. Maybe I should do with one table, and then do the calculations and then it will be dynamically updated?

**It is automatically updated only when I add new data somewhere in the middle of .csv but not when is in a last row, then it is not expanding!**

Comment: Check if it is activated in File › Options › Proofing › Autocorrect › Autoformat as you type › Include new rows and columns into table (needs to be checked). *Note this is translated (so the actual wording might be slightly different).*

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  Unfortunately I checked that even before I posted. So it is not the clue. 
But is there a difference if I firstly calculate some columns and then transform them into table, or is better to make table first and then do the calculating with named ranges and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. How? Using Power Query at its best, I played around and actually gave me complete another approach to my problem, using Merge function and a bit of formatting. Works flawlessly, with minimum functions afterwards. What is important it refreshes in a milisecond - PROPERLY!!!

I am amazed by PQ and its functionality.